# Pandas: remove rows that are in another dataframe, comparison on a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, X and Y with the same columns, and I'm trying to remove rows in X that appear in Y, but I want to compare them only based on a subset of the columns.

Example:

```
>>> X
  site_domain  id            url
0       a.com   1  ad_a.com/test
1       b.com   2  ad_b.com/test
2       c.com   3  ad_c.com/test
3       d.com   4  ad_d.com/test
4       e.com   5  ad_e.com/test

>>> Y
  site_domain  id                url
0       a.com   1      ad_a.com/test
1       b.com  10      ad_b.com/test
2   other.com   3      ad_c.com/test
3       d.com   4  ad_other.com/test
```

I want to remove rows from X that appear in Y, in my definition, this means that columns `site_domain` and `url` must match, but I don't care about `id`. The result of my operation should thus be:

```
  site_domain  id            url
0       c.com   3  ad_c.com/test
1       d.com   4  ad_d.com/test
2       e.com   5  ad_e.com/test
```

How could I do this? I think this would require some boolean mask applied on X, but I don't know how to generate a boolean mask that would apply to the index (so as to keep or reject entire rows at a time), and I also don't know how to generate such a mask.

I tried to create such a mask with `X['site_domain'] == Y['site_domain'] & X['url'] == Y['url']` and then using the negation of that mask, but Pandas complains that these series are not identically labeled. I could probably make versions of these series with identical labels, but I feel like this would be a lot of trouble for such a simple problem.

Comment: Do you compare x rows with same index of y or with every row of y?

Comment: Same index, @Vaishali found a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate site_domain and url and use `isin` to check if the concatenated string is present in Y

```
X[~(X['site_domain']+'_'+X['url']).isin(Y['site_domain']+'_'+Y['url'])] 


site_domain id  url
2   c.com   3   ad_c.com/test
3   d.com   4   ad_d.com/test
4   e.com   5   ad_e.com/test
```